# Jquery for metaboxes plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, meta-boxes

Im using jQuery for other elements on my admin page where I edit pages but with this plugin it refuses to even cast a simple `alert`

Jquery:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="target">
Click here
</div>
```

I even tried to load jquery in my document:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

To no avail. If I only run regular javascript it works as intended:

```
alert("test");
```

gives the alert as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript is not working because you are not calling the anonymous function. A better way to write your code would be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
     $( "#target" ).click(function() {
       alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
});
```

This calls the jQuery(document).ready() function, which executes the enclosed anonymous function when the DOM has fully loaded.

Helpful links:

[Using jQuery in WordPress](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/)

[Self-Executing Anonymous Functions or How to Write Clean Javascript](http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write)